# nsurl doesn't load sites if http or https not include

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a textbox which I can type in an url in to. The problem is if I just type in 'cnn.com' or any site without 'http://' in front, the page does not load. Is there a way to fix this?

I searched the apple documentation but I could not locate the help I was looking for.

My code:

```
NSString *zzz = URLbox.text;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:zzz];
[webBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if the input URL (URLbox.text) starts with either `http://` or `https://` and if it doesn't, prefix it with `http://`.

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it working:    `NSString *myURLString = URLbox.text;
    NSURL *myURL;
    
    if ([myURLString hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
        myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
    } else {
        
        NSString *rer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", myURLString];
        
        myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:rer];
        rer = URLbox.text;;
        NSLog(@"updated textbox");
        
    }`

Answer (score 4):

A URL include a scheme, unless it's relative as part of a document. `cnn.com` is a casual abbreviation for `http://cnn.com` or `http://www.cnn.com`. Browsers normally add `http://` automatically to what you type in the location bar before submitting the request.

You should check that whether the user's string starts with a scheme (not necessarily just `http://` or `https://`, but that might be sufficient in your use-case) and add one by default if it's missing.